# Multisite continuous integration (CI) setup

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit

We have a requirement to setup CI at multiple geographically separated locations. If anyone can help understand whether it is possible and in that case what should be right implementation strategy.

Right now we have CI setup in one geography (call it geo1) and are looking to replicate it to another location (call it geo2). All changes are currently submitted to geo1. In geo2 as of now we just have a git (cache ) server which takes sync for git server running in geo1 and users pull in changes from it.

We want jenkins, gerrit and git at both geo1 and geo2 to be able to sync with each other and users should be able to submit changes to any/both locations.

Any leads into this is much appreciated.

**EDIT:** So far i was able to find some clue for setting up gerrit and jenkins.

1) Mulit-master gerrit: https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/multi-master/+/8ea591720e075bb115929d3f64ef8bae21c5173b/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md

2) Jenkins: Master-slave can be achieved using HA plugin in our jenkins version, which will be ok for us to use.